# Positioning "Parallax" in Bootstrap with CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, parallax

How do I position this "parallax" code in the section tag so that the video starts after navigation bar.

I made the navigation bar transparent so we could see how the lady's head is under it. I would like we could somehow lower this so that her head no longer get cut off.

[Example Demo](http://2mp.co/example)

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `header` section have 74px height, you can add padding-top:74px to the .`wrapper` div. This Works even in responsive mode. give this a try.

```
.wrapper{
padding-top: 74px;
}
```

Hope This Works..

Comment: However when I changed the height of the video, it went back to how it was before :(

Comment: Would you happen to know a solution for this?